# Python Syslog add Tag and facility

Tags: python, syslog

I am using the python [syslog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/syslog.html) library. I want to add a `tag` and `facility` to the log. But there doesn't seem to be a way to add a `tag`.

There is a `facility` argument, but I need a **custom** string.

Is there a way to achieve something like the following:

```
import syslog
syslog.openlog(logoption=syslog.LOG_PID, facility="myapp", tag="mytag")
syslog.syslog('myapp processing initiated...')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python `syslog` library doesn't have a `tag` argument.

> syslog.openlog([ident[, logoption[, facility]]])

Instead you can use the `ident` argument.

```
syslog.openlog("mytag", logoption=syslog.LOG_PID, facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL0)
```

The `facility` instead cannot be a string like "myapp". It's the file where the logs should be written to.

> Facilities:
>
> LOG_KERN, LOG_USER, LOG_MAIL, LOG_DAEMON, LOG_AUTH, LOG_LPR, LOG_NEWS, LOG_UUCP, LOG_CRON, LOG_SYSLOG, LOG_LOCAL0 to LOG_LOCAL7, and, if defined in <syslog.h>, LOG_AUTHPRIV.

Comment: >>> syslog.openlog("mytag", logoption=syslog.LOG_PID, facility="myapp")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: it is not working

Comment: My bad, i've copy pasted the facility from the example. I've updated my answer.